# how to call map method in test class can anyone give me some idea

Tags: apex, unit-test

how to call map method in test class can anyone give me some idea

```
public Map<EnrolmentForm__c, List<String>> EFProcess(EnrolmentForm__c EF_Record)
{


//logic here

}
}
```

---

```
public Map<EnrolmentForm__c, List<String>> EFProcess(EnrolmentForm__c EF_Record){
      EF_RecordRef = EF_Record;
      List<String> ValidationsList;
      Map<EnrolmentForm__c,List<String>> EFMap = new Map<EnrolmentForm__c, List<String>>(); 
      Map<string,EFRecordTypes__c> EFRecordTypes = EFRecordTypes__c.getAll();   
      if(EF_Record.RecordType.Name ==EFRecordTypes.get('StandardEnrolment').EnrolmentRecordType__c)  
       {
             ValidationsList = new List<String>{'Salutation','Name','Signature'};
       }

    }
```

Comment: simple in your test class `Map<EnrolmentForm__c, List<String>> obj = cls.EFProcess(Record);` like that.. Also put asserts to check `obj`  map value

Comment: variable doesnot exist Record

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: EnrolmentFormValidationService.EFProcess()

Comment: you need to change two things i.e. `cls` and `Record` .. cls means first create `EnrolmentFormValidationService cls = new EnrolmentFormValidationService();` then use `Map<EnrolmentForm__c, List<String>> obj = cls.EFProcess(Record);` here `Record` means frst create `EnrolmentForm__c EF_Record`  record and pass in that method

Comment: EnrolmentForm__c Tr1=new EnrolmentForm__c(FormValidationFlag__c = true,Objection_Reporter_Salutation__c = 'Other'); i should place that tr1  instance in cls.rEFprocess(Tr1); am i correct

Comment: Yes correct.. one thing before that you may want to insert that record.. then pass record to `cls.rEFprocess(Tr1); `

Comment: error like  System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: where i can't see your code?

Comment: public Map<EnrolmentForm__c, List<String>> EFProcess(EnrolmentForm__c EF_Record){ EF_RecordRef = EF_Record;List<String> ValidationsList;Map<EnrolmentForm__c,List<String>> EFMap = new Map<EnrolmentForm__c, List<String>>(); Map<string,EFRecordTypes__c> EFRecordTypes = EFRecordTypes__c.getAll();
if(EF_Record.RecordType.Name ==EFRecordTypes.get('StandardEnrolment').EnrolmentRecordType__c)
        { ValidationsList = new List<String>{'Salutation','Name','Signature'};
        }

Comment: Change `if(EF_Record.RecordType.Name ==EFRecordTypes.get('StandardEnrolment').EnrolmentRecordType__c)` to like this `if(EFRecordTypes.containsKey('StandardEnrolment') && EF_Record.RecordType.Name ==EFRecordTypes.get('StandardEnrolment').EnrolmentRecordType__c)`

Comment: if(EFRecordTypes.containsKey('StandardEnrolment')...why u are using containkey can u explain

Comment: You are direct trying to access the value `EFRecordTypes.get('StandardEnrolment').EnrolmentRecordType__c)` if there is no key i.e. `StandardEnrolment` in map then it will give you null pointer exception

Comment: facing same issue even i replaced the above code

Comment: one last thing try to replace `List<String> ValidationsList;` with `List<String> ValidationsList = new List<String> (); ` After changing this if you face this issue then may be issue in you other code

Comment: working good but  ValidationsList = new List<String>{'Salutation','Name','Signature'}; these lines are not covering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35228/discussion-between-ratan-and-keerthana-chowdhary).